# "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)" validating a new user with regex using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to validate name and surname of new users. I would like to match only *letters* and *spaces*.

So I put in the model the following code:

```
name_regex = surname_regex = /[a-zA-Z’ ]+/i

validates :name, :on => :create,
  :format         => { :with => name_regex }

validates :surname, :on => :create,
  :format         => { :with => surname_regex }
```

When I navigate my RoR application in the browser I get this error:

```
<DIRECTORY of my RoR APPLICATION>/model.rb:35: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
<DIRECTORY of my RoR APPLICATION>/model.rb:35: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
<DIRECTORY of my RoR APPLICATION>/model.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
  name_regex = surname_regex = /[a-zA-Zâ€™ ]+/i
                                         ^
```

**What is wrong?**

Comment: What do you mean, “match only *chars* and *spaces*⁠”, anyway?  I mean, what kind of character isn’t a character anyway??

Comment: You are right. I will update the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using UTF-8 and Ruby 1.9 you'll need to prefix your files by adding as the first line:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

This is a hint to the parser to make sure not to interpret things using the wrong character set. Ruby 1.8 was really lax about this and it could cause trouble.

The tick character you're using there is not the regular apostrophe `'` but the smart-quote `’` that is not found in the 7-bit US ASCII character set.

Comment: The proper name of the character `’` is not smart-quote but rather RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. It is code point U+2019.

Comment: The set of apostrophic characters should probably contain at least: U+0027 APOSTROPHE, U+02B9 MODIFIER LETTER PRIME, U+02BB MODIFIER LETTER TURNED COMMA, U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE, U+02BE MODIFIER LETTER RIGHT HALF RING, U+02C8 MODIFIER LETTER VERTICAL LINE, U+02EE MODIFIER LETTER DOUBLE APOSTROPHE, U+0313 COMBINING COMMA ABOVE (Psili), U+0315 COMBINING COMMA ABOVE RIGHT, U+1FBF GREEK PSILI, U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK, U+2032 PRIME, and U+FF07 FULLWIDTH APOSTROPHE.

Comment: I say "smart quote" because that's how people usually get them. Word has a habit of inserting them unprompted and then, when people paste that document into something, they end up confused.

Comment: cool hint for adding this line to all ruby files using vim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4804802/72176