# Ruby: how to add "# encoding: UTF-8" automatically?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

Is there any gem which adds `# encoding: UTF-8` to each Ruby file automatically?

Or is there any other way to prevent from the `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` error in the entire Ruby on Rails project (not in a single class only)?

Comment: This isn't what you asked for, but for what it's worth some text editors (e.g. emacs) automatically insert "#encoding: UTF-8" at the top when you save a ruby file containing UTF-8.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try [magic_encoding](https://github.com/m-ryan/magic_encoding) gem, it can insert uft-8 magic comment to all ruby files in your app.

[EDIT]
Having switched to SublimeText now I use [auto-encoding-for-ruby](https://github.com/elomarns/auto-encoding-for-ruby) plugin.

Comment: note that this won't be a dependency, it's a tool that edits all the files for you. you can uninstall afterwords if you want

Comment: This is Atom version for [auto-encoding-for-ruby](https://atom.io/packages/auto-encoding-for-ruby)

Comment: @Mirko Did you get the auto-encoding-for-ruby plugin to work with Sublime Text 3 ?

Comment: @Mirko Hm, I'm also on ruby 2.x, but I was having problems with running certain scripts in the irb console for some reason.

Answer (score 31):

Upgrade to [Ruby 2.0](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/02/24/ruby-2-0-0-p0-is-released/), as it makes UTF-8 the default encoding, removing the need for magic comments.

Comment: @Subimage I believe most legacy code should work in the newer versions of ruby, the other way is harder.

Answer (score 7):

Vim:

```
:args **/*.ruby
:set hidden
:argdo norm! O# encoding: UTF-8
:wqa
```

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion. For me, vim crashed (segfault) on the `:wqa` command during the write, resulting in some written files and a bunch of .swp. So I ended up using `:wa`, then `:q` which worked fine. Of course, change `.ruby` to `.rb` if the latter is your ruby extension.

Comment: @William Denniss: Another one: `argdo 0put ='#encoding: UTF-8'`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Sublime Text 2, you can use a plugin that automatically includes encoding declaration when needed: https://github.com/elomarns/auto-encoding-for-ruby.

Answer (score 2):

How about just running a script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.1
require 'find'

fixfile = []

Find.find('.') do |path|
  next unless /\.rb$/.match(path);
  File.open(path) do |file|
    count = 0;
    type = :lib
    file.each do |line|
      if count == 0 and /#!/.match(line)
        type = :script
      end
      if  /utf/.match(line)
        break
      end
      if (count += 1) > 10 then
        fixfile.push path:path, type:type
        break
      end
    end
    if file.eof?
        fixfile.push path:path, type:type
    end
  end
end

fixfile.each do |info|
  path = info[:path]
  backuppath = path + '~'
  type = info[:type]
  begin
     File.delete(backuppath) if File.exist?(backuppath)
     File.link(path, backuppath)
  rescue Errno::ENOENT => x
     puts "could not make backup file '#{backuppath}' for '#{ path }': #{$!}"
     raise
  end
  begin
    inputfile = File.open(backuppath, 'r')
    File.unlink(path)
    File.open(path, 'w') do |outputfile|
      if type == :script
        line = inputfile.readline
        outputfile.write line
      end
      outputfile.write "# encoding: utf-8\n"
      inputfile.each do |line|
        outputfile.write line
      end
      inputfile.close
      outputfile.close
    end
  rescue => x
    puts "error: #{x} #{$!}"
    exit
  end
```

To make it automatic add this to your Rakefile.

You could run `file -bi #{path}` and look for *charset=utf-8* if you only want to update files that have utf-8 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `# encoding: UTF-8` to each Ruby file automatically makes only sense, when your files are really stored in UTF-8.

If your files are encoded CP850 (AFAIK default in Windows) and you use Non-ASCII characters, you replace `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` with `invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)`.

I would prefer a manual modification and check of each file, if it is really UTF-8.