# How does `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` work in ruby?

Tags: ruby, comments

In Ruby, `#` is used for comments. Then, how will:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

be detected? Will it ignore this line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804742/ruby-how-to-add-encoding-utf-8-automatically

Answer (score 1):

It's a magic comment.

From [Script encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Encoding.html#class-Encoding-label-Script+encoding):

> The default script encoding is `Encoding::UTF-8` after v2.0, but it can be changed by a magic comment on the first line of the source code file (or second line, if there is a shebang line on the first). The comment must contain the word coding or encoding, followed by a colon, space and the Encoding name or alias.